# IBM Worklight 6.2. Analytics installation on Linux 64 bits. Issue with lib libsigar-amd64-linux.so

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

I' trying to install analytics in a WAS 8.5 standalone server in a Linux redhat 6 64 bits.

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After installing the .war in the server and configuring the classloader with parent last, when I try to access to the console I get this exception in the log although the console is displayed.

```
[8/6/14 12:31:16:501 EDT] 00000051 SystemOut     O 0 [WebContainer : 1] DEBUG Sigar  - libsigar-amd64-linux.so (Not found in java.library.path)
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: libsigar-amd64-linux.so (Not found in java.library.path)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.sigar.SigarService.<init>(SigarService.java:40)
    at org.elasticsearch.monitor.MonitorModule.configure(MonitorModule.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:204)
```

I have not found any documentation about this in the Knowledge center or even in google.
We have tried with yum but we haven't found the lib.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a defect. The workaround is to open the analytics WAR file and delete the following directory:

WEB-INF/lib/sigar

The analytics console isn't using sigar, so there shouldn't be any issues when deleting this folder.

Comment: Easy solution. Do you know when is plan the fix? This is for a customer installation also. Thank you

Comment: Although I said that the console was displayed, until I have corrected the .war file no data was displayed.

Comment: It will definitely be fixed in the next version of Worklight. Whether it will be backported for an ifix/fixpack is to be determined since it only occurs on limited platforms and the workaround isn't too painful.

Comment: Fix included in IF201408201350 for 6.2